# Trying to read text input in java from terminal using args[0]

Tags: java, macos, file, input, terminal

When I try to execute my .java program from terminal Mac using command :
javac filename.java inputfile

It is throwing the error that "inputfile" are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

but in the program I do have command as follow:

```
    String fileinput = args[0];
     File file = new File(fileinput);
    out= getContents(file);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use `java ClassName inputfile` as the command to execute the class. You are currently using `javac` which is used to compile the `.java` file.

Comment: Oops , thank you .

Answer (score 1):

When we execute a Java program ProgramName using the following syntax:

```
java  ProgramName  word0  word1  ...
```

the Java system will pass the words:

```
word0 to the first String parameter variable
word1 to the second String parameter variable
And so on.
```

But you are using `Javac` and its compiling .java. You should use `java`